# Hypothesis testing coefficients

Tags: statistics

I've got a linear model: $y_i={\beta}_0+β_1x_{1i}+β_2x_{2i}+ε_i$ for i=1,...,N

The question asks to construct a test of $H_0$:${\beta}_1-{\beta}_2=5$ at 5% significance level using OLS estimator and its estimated variance-covariance matrix.

I've got the OLS estimators for ${\beta}_1$ and ${\beta}_2$ but I don't understand how to construct the variance-covariance matrix given I have no numbers or anything to help me.

Any ideas?

Also, in another part of the question it says, if $x_{2i}$ were omitted in the model, what can you tell about the estimator of ${\beta}_1$? Is $s^2$ an unbiased estimator of ${\sigma}^2$? 
I think all that needs to be said about ${\beta}$ is that it is biased, but I'm not sure what to do for the variance part?

Thanks